# Using results from scriptDB to add to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-apps-script

How can I add a new div tag for each item in scriptDB?

It looks like the code gets stuck when I get to the "while (results.hasNext())" part, possibly because I am using Apps Script syntax in the script section of the HTML. I am able to make the script work when I substitute the entire while loop with just a simple div.innerHTML...etc. line

the index.html file looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <p>Name of Alert: <input name="alertName" type="text" /></p>

    <select name="frequency">
    <option value="everyDay">Every day</option>
    <option value="everyWeek">Every week</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Submit"
        onclick="google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(updateAlertList)
        .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

<script>
function updateAlertList(results) {

var div = document.getElementById('output');
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        var result = results.next();
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com">' + result.alertName + '</a>';
    }
}
</script>
```

The Code.gs file has this in it:

```
function processForm(formObject) {

    var formAlertName = formObject.alertName;
    var formFrequency = formObject.frequency;

    var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
    var alert = {
    alertName: formAlertName,
    frequency: formFrequency
    };
    var record = db.save(alert);

    var results = db.query({});

    return results;
}
```

Update: worked when I added this to code.gs

```
var arrayResults = [];

while (results.hasNext()) {
    arrayResults.push(results.next()); 
}

return arrayResults;
```

and this to index.html

```
for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
{ 
alert(results[i].alertName);
div.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.google.com">' + results[i].alertName + '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to process the results (iterator) in the gs and create an array of results to work through in the javascript.